# Valgrind Memory Analyzer results

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I am using Valgrind Analyzer for the first time.

I have a long program so I cant post the code. Problem is I get segmentation faults when I run my program, but not consistent ones. I have a loop and when I run it for small number of iterations program finishes without errors. When I try more iterations, I get segmentation faults in different places depending on the numbers of loops probably. I write my code in qt creator 3.0.1 in ubuntu 14.04. The program is written in c++ and also uses some opencv libraries.

When I run Valgrind Memory Analyzer I get this output but cant really figure out what the problem is. Also the Analyzer finishes with the quote "** unknown error **"

```
Invalid write of size 4 in main in /home/esigalas/qt-workspace/builds/New-Train-SVM-build/main Address 0xffed6e770 is on thread 1's stack
1: main in /home/esigalas/qt-workspace/builds/New-Train-SVM-build/main

Invalid write of size 2 in main in /home/esigalas/qt-workspace/builds/New-Train-SVM-build/main
1: main in /home/esigalas/qt-workspace/builds/New-Train-SVM-build/main

Address 0x30c40d74 is 20 bytes after a block of size 3,392 alloc'd
1: malloc in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
2: cv::fastMalloc(unsigned long) in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.9
3: cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.9
4: cv::_OutputArray::create(int, int, int, int, bool, int) const in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.9
5: cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.9
6: main in /home/esigalas/qt-workspace/builds/New-Train-SVM-build/main
```

Comment: Make a debug build and run through Valgrind again, you will then get file-name and line-number information about where the problems are. Also run in a debugger to catch the crashes, and see where they are in your code. Build with extra warnings, warnings from the compiler are often a sign of you doing something wrong, and that can lead to undefined behavior (which you probably have). also go over all pointers, and make sure they are properly initialized before you use them, that you allocate memory when needed, and don't use memory you have already free'd.

Comment: Oh, and whenever you allocate *anything* or try to get *any* resource, make sure that it actually succeeds.

Comment: didnt manage to do any better with the Valgrind, thanks for the tips on the pointers they helped me get through my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question to answer as you doesn't provide your source code. Is it possbile to paste the source code of New-Train-SVM-build/main ?

In any case, the routine for debugging segmentation faults caused by memory leak is to remove all the code that you suspect is causing the seg fault and run the program until tou are certain the there is no memory leakage anymore. E.g use linux command top to check for increasing memory sizes and when you absolutly sure that there is no memory leakage in your program you start adding the code in minimal steps and run the program until you find the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: thanks for the tip on removing junk of codes to see whats wrong, helped me find a solution.